# Using arrow function to initialize data() in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

Why I cannot get the array of 'expired'? I can see expired is a function, but I want a array.

```
export default {
  name: 'a',
  data () {
    return {
      labelEnable: "a",
      expired: () => {
        var a = []
        for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++) { 
          a.push(i)
        }
        return a
      },
    }
  },
```

Comment: May you show how you get the value?

Comment: I use `this.expired`

Comment: you should use `this.expired()` as you have declared the expired property as a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a function which calculates expired, but you don't call and execute it. Try this:

```
  expired: (() => {
    var a = []
    for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++) { 
      a.push(i)
    }
    return a
  })(),
```

But for this particular example there is a more clear solution:

```
expired: new Array(30).fill().map((d, i) => i + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access that via `this.expired()` instead of `this.expired`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      labelEnable: "a",
      expired: () => [1, 3],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.expired())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="elem in expired()">{{ elem }}</p>
</div>
```